# Call object created from another class

Tags: java, object, encapsulation

I need `ClassB` to get the object created from `ClassA`, which is `u`. How do I do that? `ClassA` sets the value using `setSomething()` from `Utility` class, while `ClassB` should get the value set by `ClassA` using the `getSomething()` of the same object(`u`)

```
public class ClassA
{
   Utility u = new Utility()
   u.setSomething("David");
}

public class ClassB
{
   //How do I get the 'u' Utility object from ClassA
}

public class Utility
{
private String fullName;

   public void setSomething(String name)
   {
      this.fullName = name
   }

   public String getSomething()
   {
      return fullName;
   }

}
```

Comment: This is not valid code, you cannot have statements outside methods.

Comment: First, objects don't have names.

Comment: You need to take a step back and learn about variables, constructors and methods I fear. I'll still post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward approach without patterns and simple classes.

```
public class ClassA {
   private Utility u = new Utility()

   public ClassA() {
       u.setSomething("David");
   }

   public Utility getU() {
        return u;
   }
}

 public class ClassB {
     private ClassA classA = new ClassA();

     public ClassB() {
         System.out.println(classA.getU().getSomething());
     }

 }

public class Utility {
   private String fullName;

   public void setSomething(String name) {
      this.fullName = name;
   }

   public String getSomething() {
      return fullName;
   }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
}
```

Should print out 'David';

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include in ClassA and ClassB the main method. The action resides in the constructor, so how do I call the constructor from the main method?

Comment: You can generally call every constructor in any method just like: `ClassA objectA = new ClassA();` - if the constructor is defined (java adds a standard constructor if no constructor is defined).

Answer (score 1):

Note that there isn't ONE way to do things. There can be one way to do things BETTER. It all depends on your design and needs, this is just an example:

```
public class ClassA{
   Utility u = new Utility()
   public Utility getU(){
       return u;
   }
   public void buildB(){
       ClassB classB = new ClassB(this);
   }
}

public class ClassB{
   ClassA classA;
   Utility u;
   public ClassB(ClassA classA){
       this.classA = classA;
       u = classA.getU();
   }
}
```